# Building a dashboard using Google Analytics API, not sure where to start

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to build a custom dashboard pulling data from Google Analytics. My two problems:

1) Which API should I be looking into? (I've never used GA)

2) Is it possible to fake data into GA onto a local versions so I can test my dashboard in various scenarios (high traffic sites, low traffic sites, however I don't actually have access to real high traffic sites that way)

Answer (score 0):

1) [Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/), and maybe the [Realtime API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/) for realtime data from the last 30 minutes. The standard reports take 4-24 hours before they give you reliable data, the realtime API returns a subset of dimensions and metrics without any delay.

2) Realistically, no. You can use the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/)  (or even the Javascript tracker) to send fake data to a GA account (there is no "local version" of GA however), but this takes place in realtime, i.e. inserting a week of data would take you seven days. You cannot batch create hits with dates in the past.

However as a matter of architecture you should separate the data source and the actual dashboard in any case. That way you could add a fake datasource with Google-like data for testing and hook the dashboard up to Google Analytics later.